# Validar cpf's de uma query

Tags: sql, funções, oracle

Opa gente, to tentando validar os cpfs de uma query, são vários cpf"s. Tenho a seguinte função para validar cpf, porém não estou conseguindo chama-lá

Estou tentando fazer assim: `SELECT CPF_VALIDACAO(NUMR_CPF) FROM PESSOAS`.
porém não dá certo. Alguém saberia a forma correta de chamar essa função?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CPF_VALIDACAO
      (p_cpf     IN CHAR)
       RETURN    BOOLEAN
IS
     m_total     NUMBER   :=  0;
     m_digito    NUMBER   :=  0;
BEGIN
     FOR i IN 1..9 LOOP
         m_total := m_total + substr(p_cpf,i,1) * (11 - i);
     END LOOP;

     m_digito := 11 - mod(m_total,11);

     IF m_digito > 9 THEN
        m_digito := 0;
     END IF;

     IF m_digito != substr(p_cpf,10,1) THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
     END IF;

     m_digito := 0;
     m_total  := 0;

     FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
         m_total := m_total + substr(p_cpf,i,1) * (12 - i);
     END LOOP;

     m_digito := 11 - mod(m_total,11);

     IF m_digito > 9 THEN
        m_digito := 0;
     END IF;

     IF m_digito != substr(p_cpf,11,1) THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
     END IF;

     RETURN TRUE;

end;
```

Comment: O que significa "não dá certo"?

Comment: Se possivel troque k o retorno da function de boolean para number (0 não válido , 1 válido) , usar boolean em alguns frontends pode dar zebra.

Answer (score 1):

O retorno booleano pode até ser reconhecido por PL/SQL mas não por SQL.
Por esse motivo ao tentar executar a consulta:

```
SELECT CPF_VALIDACAO(NUMR_CPF) FROM PESSOAS
```

Você vai obter o erro: `ORA-00902: tipo de dados inválido`.
A única solução é alterar o retorno da sua função para `varchar` ou `number`.

Exemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cpf_validacao(p_cpf IN CHAR) RETURN NUMBER IS
  m_total  NUMBER := 0;
  m_digito NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 9 LOOP
    m_total := m_total + substr(p_cpf, i, 1) * (11 - i);
  END LOOP;

  m_digito := 11 - MOD(m_total, 11);

  IF m_digito > 9 THEN
    m_digito := 0;
  END IF;

  IF m_digito != substr(p_cpf, 10, 1) THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;

  m_digito := 0;
  m_total  := 0;

  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    m_total := m_total + substr(p_cpf, i, 1) * (12 - i);
  END LOOP;

  m_digito := 11 - MOD(m_total, 11);

  IF m_digito > 9 THEN
    m_digito := 0;
  END IF;

  IF m_digito != substr(p_cpf, 11, 1) THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;

  RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

Depois você testa assim:

```
SELECT DECODE(CPF_VALIDACAO(NUMR_CPF),1,'VALIDO','INVALIDO') FROM PESSOAS
```

Ou

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CPF_VALIDACAO(NUMR_CPF) = 1 THEN 'VALIDO' ELSE 'INVALIDO' END FROM PESSOAS
```

Comment: Apenas uma observação: o tipo de dados Boolean não é reconhecido pelo Oracle mas é por outros SGBD.

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta.

Comment: Deu certo, porém até cpfs inválidos ficam como válidos

Comment: @anonimo sim, mas como ele botou a tag, nem comentei sobre.

Comment: @CarlosHenrique você poder [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/) se ela te ajudou. Se há CPFs inválidos retornando como válidos, pode ser um problema de lógica.